# Filter features added to a branch

Tags: git, filter

I'm working in a project that we have a pattern for commiting:

`[STORY-ID-PARENT] [STORY-ID-CHILD] commit message`

I want to filter by the STORE-ID-PARENT, in order to know which features are on that branch.

**Example**:

Commits:

```
"[JIRA-01] [JIRA-01.2] commit message for item #1.2"
"[JIRA-01] [JIRA-01.3] commit message for item #1.3"
"[JIRA-02] [JIRA-02.5] commit message for item #2.5"
"[JIRA-07] [JIRA-07.4] commit message for item #7.4"
```

Would give me:

```
JIRA-01
JIRA-02
JIRA-07
```

Do you know some way to have this result?
Or a way to add a new param on git commit, to filter by it.

```
git commit -m message -feature "JIRA-01"
```

Comment: May I suggest in the future naming your feature branches by their story id? `git branch jira/07`.

Comment: Yes, we usually do it :)
But I dont think it would be easy to look to the graph of the merged branches to master :\

Comment: `git branch --merged`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git-log` has various formats, `oneline` shows you just the commit ID and first line of the message.

```
b98b956df3e1d08f42ba8feacb53244509ed0dc9 [JIRA-01] [JIRA-01.2] commit message for item #1.2
```

You can manipulate that with whatever text manipulation tools you like.

```
git-log --format=oneline | perl -le 'while(<>) { print $1 if /\[ (JIRA-.*?) \]/x }'
```

---

If you name your branches after their Jira ID, like `jira/07`, you can use `git branch --merged` to list all branches which have been merged into a branch.